Translation of gerund and absolute phrases
When reading English texts, I often encounter sentences such as:
The storks circled high above us, their slender bodies sleek and black against the orange sky.
This sentence contains an absolute phrase. Or a sentence such as:
The Nemean Lion lay in its den, its eyes emitting a predatory glow.
I am unsure how to say sentences such as these in Spanish. For the second example, do I use the gerund or the imperfect conjugation of emit? Does the first sentence make sense when translated as: Las cigüeñas volaban en círculos muy por encima de nosotros, sus cuerpos esbeltos y negros contra el cielo anaranjado?

There is one big difference between English and Spanish when it comes to translating absolute constructions: in Spanish the gerund will be placed before the subject.
If the predicate is adjectival, there is not much difference from English, but the preposition "con" ("with" can also be used in English) or a copulative in the gerund ("siendo", "estando") can be added for the sentence to flow better.
First sentence: change of order

The Nemean Lion lay in its den, its eyes emitting a predatory glow.

El león de Nemea yacía en su cueva, emitiendo sus ojos un brillo depredador.


Second sentence: adjectival predicate

The storks circled high above us, their slender bodies sleek and black against the orange sky.

Las cigüeñas volaban en círculos muy por encima de nosotros, sus cuerpos esbeltos y negros contra el cielo anaranjado: This is a very good translation. As explained above, since the predicate of the absolute construction is adjectival, we can use "con" or add a copulative gerund:

Las cigüeñas volaban en círculos muy por encima de nosotros, con sus cuerpos esbeltos y negros contra el cielo anaranjado.

Las cigüeñas volaban en círculos muy por encima de nosotros, estando sus cuerpos esbeltos y negros contra el cielo anaranjado.



Is there a website or text I could read to learn more about this?

Here You can find some useful information mainly about absolute constructions with adjectival and past participial predicates: https://www.rae.es/gram%C3%A1tica/sintaxis/las-construcciones-absolutas-i-sus-elementos-constitutivos

And here you can find examples of gerunds (absolute uses under A): https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://trad1y2ffyl.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/gramatica-los-usos-del-gerundio.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjnq4Hg2bCIAxVejpUCHVGnAKcQFnoECGAQBg&usg=AOvVaw3f-Olzix0T3QjQjm-k41yM
